# Tiff images are not rendered when using PDFKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdfkit

I am using PDFKit to generate a PDF file with Tiff images

```
kit = PDFKit.new("<img src='test.tif'")
kit.to_file("hello.pdf")
```

But in the output PDF file, Tiff images are not rendered. I have tried a JPEG file. It's working perfectly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.

Is the image in your assets folder?

Try this...

```
path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'test.tif')
kit = PDFKit.new("<img src='#{path}'>")
kit.to_file("hello.pdf")
```

Comment: Image is inside private folder.

Comment: So put the path to the private folder instead of the path I suggested.  Does that work, then?

Comment: Was the JPEG file in the same folder? Could it be a permissions issue?  Try moving the tiff to `app/assets/images` and seeing if my answer works.